# How does Asajj Ventress's lightsaber go together?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

We see that Asajj Ventress's lightsabers can come together to make a double-sided lightsaber, but her lightsaber hilts are curved. How would they come together in a way that would make it easy to use?

Comment: Have you got a picture? It might be useful.

Answer (score 7):

They fit together like this:

[image: Wookieepedia image for joined lightsabers]

She apparently could also attach them with a fiber cord to create a more flexible weapon.

As for ease of use, [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Interlocking_hilt) notes "Though she would normally use the locking mechanism, when connected by the fiber cord, the weapon was more difficult to control than a regular double-bladed saber, however, the curved hilts and the fiber cord joint of her saber gave the wielder the benefit of striking from unexpected angles." They provide citations to comics which likely show her wielding the saberstaff. Presumably, the relative clumsiness of such a grip is compensated for in part by practice and in part by the advantage provided by her opponents being unsure as to how to handle it.

So far, the images I've found almost always show her holding the staff one-handed. In some cases, she's gripping the middle with her wrist turned and in others, she's gripping closer to the blade on one side for a more standard grip.

[image: center grip] [image: offset grip]

When gripping it with both hands, she just has one arm straighter than the other:

[image: Two-handed grip]

Comment: I've spent the last 10 minutes trying to find a scene from the Clone Wars. Know what episode that is from?

Comment: Great answer, but you should probably mention what's canon and what's Legends in this answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil: It looks like it comes from the film. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Rex_shoots_at_Ventress.png

Comment: @RogueJedi: I'm no expert, but it looks like it's all sourced from official and recent books other than possibly the 2003 Mace Windu comics.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots A 2003 comic would definitely be Legends.